# NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/tooling/model/UnsupportedMethodException: org/gradle/tooling/model/UnsupportedMethodException

Tags: java, android, linux, gradle, android-studio

I wanted to import `.idea` android project with `android studio beta 0.8.2` which results with following errors:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

*removed revision content.
Gradle updated from command line.

This is ubuntu v14 system, x64.

Project's `buildscript` is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And it's `build.gradle` from module:

apply plugin: 'android'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package.id.content"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Event Log responds with:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/tooling/model/UnsupportedMethodException: org/gradle/tooling/model/UnsupportedMethodException
```

Whereas `/home/user/.gradle/wrapper/dists` contains:
[image]

Gradle-2.0-all added by myself.

Last log from AS file:

```
2014-07-20 19:46:53,849 [1014112]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - org/gradle/tooling/model/UnsupportedMethodException 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/tooling/model/UnsupportedMethodException
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.AndroidModuleEditor$2.call(AndroidModuleEditor.java:85)
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.AndroidModuleEditor$2.call(AndroidModuleEditor.java:82)
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.GenericEditor.createComponent(GenericEditor.java:49)
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.AndroidModuleEditor.getPanel(AndroidModuleEditor.java:116)
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.AndroidModuleConfigurable.createOptionsPanel(AndroidModuleConfigurable.java:62)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.NamedConfigurable.createComponent(NamedConfigurable.java:78)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.selectConfigurable(AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.java:345)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.access$300(AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.java:85)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable$SidePanel$2.valueChanged(AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.java:530)
    at javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(JList.java:1798)
    at javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(JList.java:1812)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:184)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:154)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setValueIsAdjusting(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:685)
    at javax.swing.JList.setValueIsAdjusting(JList.java:2142)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicListUI.java:2796)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:520)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:787)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:463)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGetOk(DialogWrapper.java:1557)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1524)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.editConfigurable(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:263)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.editConfigurable(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:233)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.doShowDialog(AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.java:150)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.showDialog(AndroidProjectStructureConfigurable.java:146)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.actionPerformed(AndroidShowStructureSettingsAction.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher$3.performAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:564)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:611)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.inInitState(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:463)
    at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:206)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:493)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.tooling.model.UnsupportedMethodException PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.0]
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:68)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

I see that the problem is not connected with `IDEA` project import, but `android studio` and `gradle`. If I create even a new/empty project there is the same problem:

```
Gradle 'ApplicationName' project refresh failed
Error:org/gradle/tooling/UnsupportedVersionException
```

I would appreciate any ideas how to solve this issue (RUN those imported android project).